# ActiveAdmin - customising the records that are shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

So I've got an app where users (Devise) have the ability to see either all, or a subset of main model (in this case Schools), depending on whether the user is at branch, region or national level.

```
Branch belongs_to Region
School belongs_to Branch
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to wire up the permissions (maybe with a scope) in such a way as to be transparent to ActiveAdmin. The user logs in to ActiveAdmin and is presented with a list of only the schools they're allowed to see.

So I guess this could either be an ActiveAdmin solution or something at a lower level.

Any ideas would be very welcome :)

Comment: My experience with admin frameworks has been that they are not well suited for normal site users.  I don't have experience with ActiveAdmin, however, so I can't comment on it.  It looks nice, though, and I will give it a try on my next project.

Comment: It does look quite cool doesn't it? I've got RailsAdmin in place just to get me up and running but I was going to retire that and roll my own admin from scratch - just trying to figure out if ActiveAdmin is flexible enough to be a good base instead.

Comment: Gotcha ;-)  Let us know what you find

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set it up so a user has a [polymorphic association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) to either a school, a branch or a region. If this association is nil it would mean that the user has access to everything (the national level you mentioned).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :administrates, :polymorphic => true
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :branch
  has_many :users, :as => :administrates
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :schools
  has_many :users, :as => :administrates
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :branches
  has_many :users, :as => :administrates
end
```

You can't make it completely transparent to Active Admin as you have to tell Active Admin to use the particular scope. For this you should be able to get by with `scope_to` inside your `ActiveAdmin.register` blocks. You have to do a little magic to make `scope_to` work with a polymorphic association, but it's doable:

```
ActiveAdmin.register School do
  scope_to do
    Class.new do
      def self.schools
        case current_user.administrates
        when School
          School.where(:id => current_user.administrates_id)
        when Branch
          School.where(:branch_id => current_user.administrates_id)
        when Region
          School.where(:branch_id => current_user.administrates.branches.map(&:id))
        when NilClass
          School.scoped
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This basically means that each time Active Admin will load a school (or a list of schools on the index page), it will scope it through the anonymous class we created inside the `scope_to` block.

You should be able to implement something similar on the `Branch` and `Region` models depending on your requirements.

You should be aware though, that there currently is [an open issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/70#issuecomment-2370201) when using `scope_to` with regards to filters and forms showing resources outside the current users scope.

You also need authorization to limit users on a certain level to only see that level and below (e.g. users on a branch level should not have access to regions). For this you should use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

For info on how to integrate CanCan in Active Admin, see [this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/72) or [this](http://groups.google.com/group/activeadmin/browse_thread/thread/905a7c07561266f9).

Comment: What a brilliant answer, that covers everything I need to know, thanks Thomas. Hope I can become good enough to give back to StackOverflow in the not too distant future.